# How do I put offsets between the JPanels and the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I would like to make a design like the following,

[image]

I'm trying to put the offesets between the JPanels and the Jframe and I get something similar to this, 
[image]

I have the code as following where I out the 2 JPanels inside a JFrame.

```
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My App");

        GridLayout myLayout = new GridLayout(1,2);
        myLayout.setHgap(10);

        frame.setLayout(myLayout);

        JPanel  jLeftPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel  jRightPanel = new JPanel();

        jLeftPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        jLeftPanel.setSize(275, 250);

        jRightPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        jRightPanel.setSize(275, 250);

        frame.add(jLeftPanel);
        frame.add(jRightPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(600, 550);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

How do I improve the design ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JComponent can have a border. There is a `BorderFactory` which can produce appropriate borders. For instance:

```
int top=10;
int left=10;
int bottom=10;
int right=10;
jLeftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(top,left,bottom,right));
```

This would create an empty (i.e. non-opaque) border. You could have a border with a specific color, too:

```
int thickness=10;    
jLeftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY,thickness));
```

Check out the other BorderFactory.create... methods, and if you need anything more complicated, you can create your own implementations of the `javax.swing.border.Border` interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this works. How do I put a button in the bottom right side of the left panel that would take 2 parameters (width and height) and draw the figure in the right panel ? I'm struggling on this for last 3 hours, a little help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'd use a BorderLayout for the left panel, then add two inner panels, a GridLayout panel in the center for the input text fields, and a FlowLayout panel in south for the button (FlowLayout can right align). On the right, I would subclass JPanel and draw the figure myself in an overridden JComponent.paintComponent() method. Also, Oracle has a [tutorial on custom-painted components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

Comment: Also, if you want to create complex layouts, please note that the onboard Layout managers for AWT / Swing are very limited and tedious to use on a larger scale. I recommend looking into 3rd party layout managers, in particular [JGoodies FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/).

Comment: Can you provide some sample code ? I'm trying this since yesterday